# How to disable an individual bookmark in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've ignored Visual Studio bookmarks until today.  I've now learned that I can not just mark places in code, but *name* those bookmarks, and even group them into folders.  I could potentially create a group for an issue I'm working on, and another group for a separate issue, and easily switch back and forth between what I'm working on.

You can even disable *all* bookmarks!  But there's no option to disable an *individual* bookmark.  Not in the bookmarks view.  Not in the context menu.  Not in the edit menu.

Am I missing something?

Here's screenshots for reference:

**Editor gutter bookmark**
[image: Editor gutter bookmark]

**Bookmarks sub-menu under *Edit* menu**
[image: Bookmarks sub-menu under Edit menu]

**Bookmarks window**
[image: Bookmarks window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Bookmarks window any single bookmark can be disabled by unchcking the checkbox to the left of the bookmark label. Like this in Visual Studio 2013:

[image]

You can also disable an Active bookmark by the **Edit->Bookmarks** menu and select the **Enable Bookmark** menu item. The name of that menu item is not entirely correct as it actually toggles the current bookmark between enabled/disabled states.

Comment: The poorly named menu item did, indeed, confuse me.

Comment: I don't see this "checkbox on the left of the bookmark label" you speak of.

Comment: Strange, maybe I got some extension that adds the checkboxes then... Well the screenshot I added is from VS 2013. But when I answered your question I was on my other PC with VS 2012.

Comment: @Trinition: From my point of view there is a bug in VS see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218905/enabling-disabling-bookmarks-in-visual-studio/22221913#22221913. +1 for good question.